# Why is $doCheck called twice when the view changes, and what can I do about it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the following Angular 1.7.5 code, I hook up a text box to a certain controller field with `ng-model` and use `$doCheck` to do something whenever the value changes. Note that in my actual project, the value I'm watching is an object and I need to find out whenever any of its fields change, so I have to use `$doCheck`. I know it's overkill for a textbox.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="TheController as ctrl">
    <input ng-model="ctrl.value" />
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module("app", [])
   .controller("TheController",
   class TheController
   {
       constructor()
       {
           this.value = "";
       }

       $doCheck()
       {
           console.log("check: " + this.value);
       }
   }
);
```

Whenever the value in the text box changes, you can see that `$doCheck` is called twice (both times with the new value). Why is this? How can I filter out the "pointless" `$doCheck` calls and just get the ones where the value actually changed?

Comment: With `<input>` elements, use `ng-model` and the [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive to process changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The [$digest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest) loop keeps iterating until the model stabilizes, which means that the [$evalAsync](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsync) queue is empty and the [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) list does not detect any changes.

This means that `$doCheck` will called **a minimum of two times**. Once to detect changes and again to detect that there are no new changes. If there are more changes or functions added to the `$evalAsync` list. It will be called again and again to the limit set by [`$rootScopeProvider.digestTtl(limit)`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$rootScopeProvider#digestTtl).

If detecting changes, you must store the previous value(s) for comparison to the current values.

```
this.$doCheck = function() {
    var newValue;
    var oldValue;
    oldValue = newValue;
    newValue = itemOfInterest();
    if (newValue != oldValue) {
       //Code to act on changes
    };
};
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Integration with the browser event loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop)
- [AngularJS $compile Service API Reference - Life-cycle Hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)